# Databinding an enum to a ComboBox in WPF + MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox, enums

I've read [this very related question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf), and it was extremely helpful because of the link in the answer.  I'm just having a problem now going the extra step and making it all work with the MVVM pattern.

Let's say I have my ViewModel, and it (or even the Model) could have an enum defined:

```
public enum MyTypes { Type1, Type2, Type3 };
```

I want to databind this to a ComboBox in my GUI.  According to the article, I would use an ObjectDataProvider to invoke the Enum.GetValues() method on MyTypes.  So I have to pass MyTypes as a MethodParameter.  But how do you pass the type?  I've tried various methods, like adding the reference to the namespace in XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="TipHandlingValues">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <!-- what goes here?  it's totally wrong. -->
                <my:MyTypes />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Pretty much nothing I put there will even compile.  Does anyone know how to get past this little hurdle?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to add this line in code:

```
DataContext = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyTypes));
```

Other options is to add markup extension that produce list of values out of enum.

Comment: That might be the simplest, but I don't think it's appropriate because my DataContext is my ViewModel, which is how I bind all of my commands and other comboboxes.  I have a ton of other GUI elements than just the one combobox.  As for the "other options", I thought the markup I posted in my question is how you produce the list of values from the enum?

Comment: there might be no way to do it by pure XAML. and it looks for me that it is done much easier with regular C#. Create a property in our ViewModel called MyTypesValues and bind to in then. ({Binding MyTypesValues}).

Answer (score 4):

See my answer on this SO post: [How to declare combobox itemTemplate that has Itemsource as Enum Values in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532872/how-to-declare-combobox-itemtemplate-that-has-itemsource-as-enum-values-in-wpf)

In short, in the ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters should refer to your Enum's type name as referenced in a namespace, i.e.,

```
<ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
  <x:Type TypeName="my:MyTypes"/>
</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
```