# Binding one enum

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, enums

I have an enum with each value representing an image, for example:

```
public enum AnimalImages
{
    Cow,
    Cat,
    Dog
}
```

I also have a converter that takes the enum and returns an ImageSource:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return ResourceManager.Instance.GetImageFromEnum((AnimalImages)value);
}
```

I am using WPF with MVVM; now, I want to add an image to my view. Using the `Cow` enum, I would like the cow image. I know that I can add a property to my ViewModel and call it like this:

```
public AnimalImages CowImage
{
   return AnimalImages.Cow;
}
```

and then bind it to my UI. But, I'm thinking there is a better way of doing this. Something like the following (which doesn't work of course):

```
<Image Source="{x:Static images:AnimalImages.Cow}, Converter={StaticResource AnimalImagesImageBitmapSource}}"/>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: While the following S.O. answer isn't exactly what you're asking, it provides a couple of alternatives for using images with enums and WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2534055/9664

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

That is the way to do it if the ViewModel property is an enum. It would look like this:

```
<!-- DataContext of the Image has to be the ViewModel -->
<Image Source="{Binding CowImage, Converter={StaticResource AnimalImagesImageBitmapSource}}"/>
```

### Alternative

You could also do it so that your ViewModel property `CowImage` actually returns a `URI` or an `ImageSource` of the image, that way you don't need the converter and it looks "cleaner".

Like this:

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public ImageSource CowImage
{
    get 
    {
        return ResourceManager.Instance.GetImageFromEnum(AnimalImages.Cow);
    }
}
```

**Xaml File**

```
<Image Source="{Binding CowImage}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just need to use `Binding and pass static value as Source`.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static images:AnimalImages.Cow},
                    Converter={StaticResource AnimalImagesImageBitmapSource}}"/>
```